# Linq: Using ElementAt on a database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get the 2nd element of a database using the Linq method, ElementAt.  However I am getting the below error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'PersonData.Models.Person ElementAt[Person](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[PersonData.Models.Person], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I tried doing this:

```
var P1= db.Person.ElementAt(2);
```

But in vain.
I also tried this:

```
var pl = from s in db.Persons select s;

var Person1 =pl.ElementAt(2);
```

But I get the same error.  Any idea what I am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, be aware that `ElementAt` is 0-based - if you want the second element, you should be using `ElementAt(1)`, not `ElementAt(2)`. (Think of it like array indexing.)

I'm not surprised that it's rejecting `ElementAt` on an unordered query, although I would hope for a better message. I believe that rows in a database table are inherently unordered - so taking an element by index makes little sense. (Likewise asking for the first or last element makes little sense.) Any operations relying on a position only make sense when that position is deterministic.

You can *try* ordering it first, e.g.

```
var person = db.Person.OrderBy(p => p.Id).ElementAt(1);
```

If that still doesn't work, you could try using `Skip`:

```
var person = db.Person.OrderBy(p => p.Id).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or if that *still* doesn't work:

```
var person = db.Person.OrderBy(p => p.Id).Skip(1).Take(1).AsEnumerable().First();
```

I would expect at least one of these solutions to work - and I've presented them in the order in which I'd prefer them.

Comment: OK.  So what if I want to use Linq method Last()?

Comment: @tabby: Well that would be a different question - with an ordered sequence, I expect that may well work, but you'd have to try it. An alternative is to use the reverse ordering and call `First()` instead.

Comment: Hmm yes.  So methods like ElementAt, etc need to be used on an ordered list only?

Comment: @tabby: Yes, exactly as per the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Does Linq to Entities support such operations? Is `ElementAt` convertible to a SQL query?

Comment: @mehrandvd: I don't know - that's why I've given the various options.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `db.Persons.OrderBy(p => p.Id).Skip(2).Take(1).FirstOrDefault()`